# On DC/OS how do you force the amount of memory available to an agent

Tags: mesos, dcos

I'm using the Vagrant DC/OS installation, and have added swap space to my guest to simulate a larger amount of memory.  How do I force the amount of memory available to a mesos agent

Answer (score 0):

In Mesos, you can do that via adjusting `--resources` agent flag, [see here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/). In DC/OS I believe it is highly discouraged to play with Mesos configuration directly. Use it at your own risk.